# add 2 columns to existing table in oracle with not null and make these columns to PK

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ddl

I want to add Account_Number and run_dtm columns to a existing table (accountdetails) with lots of data in oracle, both should not null, i want to make these columns (Account_Number and run_dtm ) as primary key.

Comment: So, your problem is that the existing table has `null` data and making it `not null` is throwing an error?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
SQL> create table accountdetails (id number);

Table created.

SQL> alter table accountdetails add (account_number number,
  2                                  run_dtm        number);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table accountdetails add constraint pk_ad primary key (account_number, run_dtm);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

There's no need to make those columns `NOT NULL` because primary key constraint won't allow NULLs anyway.

Before enforcing the primary key constraint, you'll have to fill those columns with values (otherwise it'll fail).